Unrecognized field \"timestamp\" (class com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.Errors), not marked as ignorable
As the heading says I am facing an error while stubbing a PUT /errors API inside a integration test and getting the below error. I want to know what is reason I am seeing this error.
Below is the integration test:
@Test
public void shouldHandleUnknownRuntimeException() {
    var rootException = new Throwable("Root cause");
    var intermediateException = new Exception("Intermediate cause", rootException);
    var originalThrowable = new Exception("Test message", intermediateException);
    var message = new GenericMessage<>(validLogisticAttributesDraft().build());
    var messageId = Optional.ofNullable(message.getHeaders().getId()).map(Object::toString).orElse(null);
    stubFor(put(urlPathEqualTo("/errors")).withHeader("Content-Type", equalTo("application/json")));

    assertThatThrownBy(() -> errorHandler.handle(message, originalThrowable)).isInstanceOf(RuntimeException.class)
            .hasMessageContaining(rootException.getMessage());
    verify(sqsTemplate, never()).send(anyString(), any());
    assertThat(messageId).isNotNull().isNotBlank();

    await().atMost(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).untilAsserted(() -> verify(eagleEyeRestClient).put());
}

stubFor(put(urlPathEqualTo("/errors")).withHeader("Content-Type", equalTo("application/json")));

I am getting error to this stubFor method.
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "code" : 10,
    "source" : {
      "pointer" : "/timestamp"
    },
    "title" : "Error parsing JSON",
    "detail" : "Unrecognized field \"timestamp\" (class com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.Errors), not marked as ignorable"
  } ]
}
com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.JsonException: {
  "errors" : [ {
    "code" : 10,
    "source" : {
      "pointer" : "/timestamp"
    },
    "title" : "Error parsing JSON",
    "detail" : "Unrecognized field \"timestamp\" (class com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.Errors), not marked as ignorable"
  } ]
}

I tried using @JsonIgnoreProperties to the class, didn't work.
